# Is this hypothesis test correct?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I have the following exercise:

> A production process is working satisfactorily if the percentage of
>   defective produced items is at most 2%. A sample of size 100 is taken
>   and it has 4 defective items. Is the production process working
>   satisfactorily? p-value= 0.14. Justify your answer.

The way I solved this test this (following a recent thread suggestion -- [How should I formulate this hypothesis test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318098/how-should-i-formulate-this-hypothesis-test)) is by setting:
$$H_0:p=0.02$$
$$H_1:p<0.02$$
However, in the solutions, they test:
$$H_0:p=0.02$$
$$H_1:p>0.02$$

Since we want to test that the proportion is *at most* 0.02, shouldn't we insert that into the alternative hypothesis?

Comment: No, what we want to test (and, in a way, what we try to reject, or the claim we want to challenge) is what we set as the null hypothesis. In this case, we want to challenge the claim that the process works satisfactorily, so we set as null hypothesis that it does, and as alternative that it is **not** working satisfactorily (more than 2% defect rate)

Comment: Notice that both your null-hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis have the same conclusion - The production process is OK.

Comment: what is the purpose of stating  p =  0.14 ?  what does it mean here ?

Comment: seems to me that it is a self-study question. If so, please add tag - self-study.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I now see that both my null and alternative hypothesis refer to the same. What I am confused about is that in my class notes, I have written: "when we wonder whether we can state something, we must write it in the alternative hypothesis". How does this apply to my case?

Comment: You have not given answer by solving the proposed problem . Just rasing questions abouut the probable hypothesis and how to construct. Try to solve the question first . "do not wonder".

Comment: I have solved the question, but that is not where I have a problem. I know the test-statistic to use and I know how to plug in the numbers. Right not I am confused about the setup of the problem. If they asked me: "is there evidence against the process being satisfactory", I would use the second option; if they asked me "is there evidence in favor of the process being satisfactory", I would use my option. Here, it is not specified.